# How to get the pixel postion relative to particular div/image (not the screen)

Tags: jquery

I am using following php code

```
<img class="hover" src="img/large_eyeball.png" style="margin-left:100px;">
<div id="co"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/1.7.2.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hover_text.js"></script>
```

Here are the contents of `hover_text.js`:

```
$('.hover').mousemove(function(e) {
    $('#co').text('x: '+ e.clientX + 'y: ' + e.clientY);    
});
$('.hover').click(function(e) {
    alert('x: '+ e.clientX + 'y: '+ e.clientY);
});
```

Using above code I'm able to get the pixel position but relative to the very left and very top of the screen; I want to get it relative to image boundary.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is by using the [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function.  (There might be a better and more direct method, however).

```js
$('.hover').mousemove(function(e) {
    var out = 'x: '+ (e.clientX - $(this).offset().left) + 'y: ' + (e.clientY - $(this).offset().top);
    $('#co').text(out);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="hover" src="//placehold.it/100x100" style="margin-left:100px;">
<div id="co"></div>
```

Comment: If i want to put a mark on image where somebody click on it. only once. Is it possible?

Comment: You can either calculate out by the x and y coordinates if a marker is clicked, but I personally would use an element with absolute positioning inside a parent wrapper with relative positioning.  The relative parent would contain both the image and the absolutely positioned child marker.  [You can see the above example using that method here](http://jsfiddle.net/b1s1oswh/)

Comment: That's just because of a minor error with the CSS.  In jsfiddle you don't need the `<style>` tag.  Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/dLn87tqy/2

Comment: yes it working fine. I was using grid. that adjust automatically according to screen. So finally I have remove grid to get it.